# Combine: difference between Just and first() to finish a stream

Tags: swift, combine

I'm new to Combine and I don't understand the behaviour in these cases:

```
func getPublisherWithFirst() -> AnyPublisher<Value, Error> {
    // somePublisher: PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>
    return somePublisher
        .compactMap { (someBool) -> Value? in
            if someBool {
                return Value()
            }
            return nil
        }
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .first()
        .timeout(.seconds(5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

```
func getPublisherWithFlatMap() -> AnyPublisher<Value, Error> {
    // somePublisher: PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>
    return somePublisher
        .flatMap { (someBool) -> AnyPublisher<Value, Never> in
            if someBool {
                return Just(Value()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            return Empty(completeImmediately: false, outputType: Value.self, failureType: Never.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .timeout(.seconds(5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

When using `getPublisherWithFlatMap`, my stream does not finish (the timeout is triggered), even if a `Just` publisher is returned and it is supposed to finish. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "issue" is caused by you using a `PassthroughSubject` as your upstream. `PassthroughSubject` never completes unless you explicitly send a completion on it.

When using `first`, it doesn't matter if the upstream completes or not, since `first` completes as soon as its upstream emits a single value. However, in case of `flatMap`, `flatMap` executes its closure on every single value emitted by its upstream and hence it only completes when its upstream completes. It doesn't matter that you return a `Just` inside your `flatMap`, that `Just` will only be returned for a single value, not for the upstream as a whole.

If you want to ensure that `getPublisherWithFlatMap` also completes after emitting a single value, you should call `first` on it as well, similarly to `getPublisherWithFirst`.

```
func getPublisherWithFlatMap() -> AnyPublisher<Value, Error> {
    // somePublisher: PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>
    return somePublisher
        .flatMap { (someBool) -> AnyPublisher<Value, Never> in
            if someBool {
                return Just(Value()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            return Empty(completeImmediately: false, outputType: Value.self, failureType: Never.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .first()
        .timeout(.seconds(5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: This part is the confusing one for me: _It doesn't matter that you return a Just inside your flatMap, that Just will only be returned for a single value, not for the upstream as a whole._. Well, I think I need to read again `flatMap` documentation. Thank you!

Comment: If you're familiar with marble diagrams, [the diagram on this page](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) may help you understand `flatMap`. If you're not familiar with marble diagrams, [read this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jshvarts/read-marble-diagrams-like-a-pro-3d72934d3ef5). Rx's `Observable` = Combine's `Publisher`.